# Jira plugin development - Is it possible to customize the 'Add project' page from a plugin?

Tags: plugins, project, jira, customization

I am developing a JIRA plugin and I'm trying to add a custom field to the `Add project` page. As far as I know, a custom field can be added only for an issue. Is it possible to add a custom field (a text field or a select list) at a project level?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer: doable but not particularly easily

The way you do this is to write a WebWork plugin that changes the Java class that handles that webpage. The process is that the actions.xml file contains the AddProjects.jspa, e.g.

```
<action name="project.AddProject" alias="AddProject" roles-required="admin">
    <view name="error">/secure/admin/views/addproject.jsp</view>
    <view name="input">/secure/admin/views/addproject.jsp</view>
</action>
```

which tells you that the class name is AddProject, which you can extend to handle the user setting a value in this new field. Then you also need to decide how you're going to store values for each project (more info in the Practical JIRA Plugins or JIRA Development Cookbook books). The hardest part here is that the template files are .jsp files which you can't change directly with a plugin. What I usually do is write a ServletFilter to inject JavaScript to change the AddProjects page that way.

Answer (score 1):

I have found an plugin, which is able to add metadata on Project level.

Please take a glimpse at [this](https://marketplace.atlassian.com/plugins/com.osoboo.jira-metadata-plugin) link

Answer (score 0):

There is no elegant way, but you possibly can use [Custom Project Properties for JIRA](https://plugins.atlassian.com/plugin/details/35576) plugin.

This plugin allows to:

- define list of custom fields for projects
- define custom fields per project
- fill custom fields on project administration page